# Map node port directly into pod, bypassing services and ingress

Tags: kubernetes, port

Is there a way to map a port directly from the node to a pod running on the same node, bypassing services, loadbalancers and ingress. So basically if a pod is deployed on node X, then node X needs to listen on port 1234 and map that port directly into a pod also running on node X on port 1234. So basically there would be no cross node connections. And whatever node Kubernetes decides to deploy the POD on, that node is now the new host for the external connections.

I am fully aware that this goes against all design principles of a Kubernetes cluster. But I am trying to host an old custom build cloud app that was built for a once only custom cloud solution, and see if I can host it on Kubernetes, but each POD in the stateful set needs a dedicated public IP assigned to it as the public IP get's sent to external devices to redirect them to the correct POD. And the protocol is also custom so there doesn't exist an Level 7 loadbalancer for this. So the only solution I can come up with is a direct port mapping from the node into the POD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hostNetwork: true` and `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet` in the pod spec

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

This means the pod will listen on the port `8080` directly using the host's network and can be accessed via `nodeip:8080` without creating a `service` or `ingress`.

Comment: I have tried this and it does work, but now the pod is unable to resolve other service names inside the Kubenetes cluster. Is there a way to make service names resolvable again?

Comment: I also tried hostPort. But hostPort is still broken if you use kube-proxy.

Comment: Ok. I got it working now. The option that worked was hostNetwork: true. But it's also very important to set "dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet" so that services are resolvable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a `Service` with a `NodePort` type? This will give you a "static" port on each node to which the pod is deployed. The port number will be high (30000+) but reliable. This is described [in the narrative documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport).

Comment: I have tried this but the problem is that the port number can't be changed between pods the application wasn't built for the originally. So I can change the port number, but then it has to be the same on all pods.